# Not able to find match in array and print in perl webpage

Tags: perl, cgi, html

I'm trying to build a webpage in perl, where I get a name from a textfield and then compare it with a array. If the match is found , I need to display some corresponding contents that are stored in a textfile.  Here is my code,

```
#!G:\perl\bin\perl.exe -w

use CGI qw/:standard/;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $action = $cgi->param('action');


my @team = qw( red blue green yellow );


print
header,
start_html('welcome'),
h1('welcome'),
start_form,
"Please Enter your name",textfield('name'),p,  //can someone tell me what is ,p, doing here?
submit,
end_form,
hr,"\n";

my $n = $cgi->param('name');


for (my $i=0; $ <= $#team; $i++) {
if ( $team[$i] eq $n ) {

print "Welcome, $n";


}else {
print "who are you ?";
}

}
 print end_html;
```

My problem is Im not able to compare after getting the name and also not able to print anything after getting the name. Also Is it possible to change the text inside submit button ?

Comment: First, your comment is not a comment. A comment in Perl is a `#`, not `//`. The `p` will create a paragraph `<p>`. I don't know why you would want an empty paragraph there. You'r still not using `strict` btw, though you do have `warnings` through the `-w`.

Comment: You will sure get several answers to point out where you have problems. But, at the start - consider to use `Plack` to any project. (small or big ones). You will get helpers, what GREATLY simplifies many things around...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text on the submit button like this:

```
print submit(-value=>'text on the submit button');
```

Please **do refer to the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/CGI#CREATING-A-SUBMIT-BUTTON)** of CGI for more details. It pays off to read that stuff.

---

There's also a typo in the code. That probably causes your code not to `print` anything after you got `$n`. You would have noticed with `use strict`.

```
for (my $i=0; $ <= $#team; $i++) {
            # ↑
            # └─ This is supposed to be $i
```